# Translate a string with point separated into array keys

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have an string (like `one.two.three` or `month.2`) and I need to translate this string exploding point character into array keys.

So I have `month.2` and I need the codeline to translate this string into `$lang['month'][2]`

I was looking for that solution but I am not able to find it, I am blocked.

---

I finally found this:

```
<?php
$lang['one']['two']['three'] = 'well done';

$str = 'one.two.three';
$list = explode('.', $str);
$result = '$lang';
foreach ($list as $item)
{
    $result .= '["'.$item.'"]';
}

var_dump(eval("return " . $result.';'));
?>
```

Comment: Please consider answering your own question instead of editing the answer into the question. You can even accept it. **Note**: I would strongly advise against using this `eval` solution. You should only use `eval` when you have no other way (so almost never).

Answer (score 4):

Start by exploding it:

```
$in = explode('.', $in);
```

Then rewrite it as a nested array:

```
$arg = array();
foreach (array_reverse($in) as $key) {
   $arg = array($key => $arg);
}
```

And finally merge:

```
$out = array_merge_recursive($arg, $out);
```

---

Edit: in case you're seeking to *read* the array instead, then bazmegakapa's answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: This one is neat. I was going to suggest something similar, just not that well laid out.
However, I'd suggest using `array_merge_recursive`, in case there are more strings to be parsed, e.g. `'one.two.three'` and then `'one.two.five'`

Comment: One of us misunderstood the question :).

Comment: @bazmegakapa: I'm suspecting I did, and that your code (gets my +1) is what he's looking for at the end of the day. The question is painfully unclear though. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little recursive function to handle this. First you explode the string, and pass the array (`$lang` in your example, `$a` in mine) and this exploded array to `GetVal()`. It will do its best to return the needed value into `$x`.

```
$s="month.2";
$keys=explode('.', $s);
$a=array(
    'month' => array('1' => 'fos', '2' => 'fos2'),
    'retek' => 1
);

function GetVal($array, $keyarray) {
    $key=array_shift($keyarray);
    if (array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
        if (count($keyarray)==0) {
            return $array[$key];
        } else {
            return GetVal($array[$key], $keyarray);
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

$x=GetVal($a, $keys);
var_dump($x);
```

Answer (score -1):

Its a clarification for the use of explode function:

```
<?php
$str = "Hello world. It's a beautiful day.";
print_r (explode(" ",$str));
?>
```

this code explodes as:

```
Array
(
[0] => Hello
[1] => world.
[2] => It's
[3] => a
[4] => beautiful
[5] => day.
)
```

not as Array[hello][world][its][a].......

Comment: I guess the poster could have been clearer but I think they were trying to convey a concept versus specifying which function they want to use the for the solution. Obviously explode() will not work here.

Comment: I can understand the fact but the user must have specified that he doesnt know about explode, or he hasnt used it.

Comment: <?php
$lang['one']['two']['three'] = 'well done';

$str = 'one.two.three';
$list = explode('.', $str);
$result = '$lang';
foreach ($list as $item)
{
    $result .= '["'.$item.'"]';
}

var_dump(eval("return " . $result.';'));